# Reg expression for finding expression in sentence

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a regular expression that match the string that contains the word "duration", followed by a `<` or `>` operator and then a number. Here is the expression:

```
duration\s*(<|>)\s*([0-9]+)
```

Is there any way I can make this expression better?

Comment: Can you give some example input and output text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only have two characters to compete with, namely, `<` and `>`, use a character set. Other than that, you might consider `\d` matching your digits, instead of `0-9` as `\d` covers the numerical characters across the entire UTF8 range.

The final expression would be:

```
duration\s*([<>])\s*(\d+)
```

I've left the matching groups in place, considering that you might be referencing them in your later code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only **duration**  keyword after that either < or > sign & then the 1 or more numeric value then use below one regex which simple.

```
duration([<>])(\d+)
```

I removed the character which are not required.